# some more help for naming conventions plural vs singular

Tags: node.js, rest, resources, uri, naming-conventions

There are answers out there but my question is different as I'm trying to find out a uri when I've detail on a product or when I've to return detail on a product plus it's customers. I need a standard solution for following 4 api calls. I need a standard naming convention for this particular situation, please fix them from the following.

**Plural (with s)**

`GET /products` - List all products

`GET /products/1` - Detail of the product ONLY (no customers)

**Singular**

`GET /product/1` - Detail of a product plus it's customers

`GET /product/1/customers` ONLY customers of product 1

From the above I'm trying to find a solution for these two.

`GET /products/1` - Detail of the product ONLY (no customers)

`GET /product/1` - Detail of a product plus it's customers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't use differen URLs to differentiate between the product with and without customers. Use [content negotioation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation).

To get a product **with embedded customers**, use one `Accept` header:

```
GET /products/1
Accept: application/vnd.com.example.rest.customer.long+json
```

To get a product **without customers**, use a different `Accept` header.

```
GET /products/1
Accept: application/vnd.com.example.rest.customer.short+json
```

But always use **the same URL** since you are requeting **the same resource**. To request **diferent representations** of this URL, use content negotiation.

Comment: Great, thanks, I noticed you used the plural form, `GET /products/1`, I got mixed up with them, isn't singular used to query one single item? in this case `GET /product/1`

Comment: I would name the resource `/products` (plural) since this is the *collection resource* of all products.

Comment: ok, what would you use `DELETE /products/1`, `PUT /products/1`, `POST /products/1` (plural) as well?

Comment: Yes. `/products/1` identifies the product with ID 1. But REST does not care. The important thing is to be consistent.

Comment: how'd you output JSON for the `/products/1`, an array [{id: 1, name: "john"}] which I've be dumping the `rows` (node.js) straight out to the client, or should I go, check the length and return `rows[0]` and return as an object `{id: 1, name: john}`

Comment: I'd return only the object, not the array.

Comment: Where can i learn more about this `vnd.com`, I've learned that it's some form of custom media type

Comment: Hi Lutz, another question since you seem like really knowledgeable in this, how about post requests, an end point that receives insert for the parent table, and same end point that receives the data for the parent table as well as child tables (linked via foreign keys etc.), how do I specify both kinds to a single end point (POST)?

Comment: Just ask a new question if you have a new question. I'll try to answer if you ping me by using @LutzHorn in a comment.

Comment: I did, not sure if you got some kind of notification